# Number of all cycles in permutations is equal to n!

Tags: permutations, permutation-cycles

It might be a well known fact, but I wanted to clarify if it is correct to state that the number
of all possible n-permutation cycles (unsigned Stirling numbers of first kind) is factorial of n?

$$ \sum_{k=1}^{n} c(n,k) = n! $$

If correct, I assume that one could prove the statement by looking at canonical cycle notation of each permutation and argue that there exists a unique way to put parentheses to form cycles.*.

*by the lemma given in my textbook (Bona, A Walk Through Combinatorics, p130):

Lemma 6.15 (Transition Lemma). Let p : [n] → [n] be a permutation
written in canonical cycle notation. Let g(p) be the permutation obtained
from p by removing the parentheses and reading the entries as a permutation
in the one-line notation. Then g is a bijection from the set Sn of all
permutations on [n] onto Sn.

I apologize if it is an obvious statement, I just wanted to clarify that it is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the proof, from Bolker and Gleason, [Counting Permuations](https://pdf.sciencedirectassets.com/272565/1-s2.0-S0097316500X01082/1-s2.0-0097316580900126/main.pdf?X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjENj%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJHMEUCICDPdXIR9p4q%2FMfhuFK71izLTJ%2Fj7CMMAdIqKrH1xBEVAiEA2HOVJHSLVSQEMh877l1oGbj0ndnVTNx1EMCxhIe60osqvQMIkP%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FARACGgwwNTkwMDM1NDY4NjUiDIfXMwJ6cIyN4TjJJCqRA4D6%2BXD5YMFlj9YDS9PiL7WP1Rwl8t7agUs1Sr0C1eFVOMg%2BcpcbYrC5uTRSOHjsYtTdQGQn1Cf2LK1rp1VqN4vnzrzeZQt%2BcGecddbyWMqdgv3cCg5xOcr%2Fm3PayF3qzHtQLnPvyiBTfLwN7hu328t1XDxHAfdx6MxBI6L8hpGa0vSwt1hqrJugr4kN5Ilm7rVmU3K0IbMkV%2BES4vN8xDYxtEilv9ccFWCR74vbwUJ%2FSp3deQ%2BpEpBky1Eq1bD3gxc705A%2BIMk3wY%2FxoNwTRXJnm%2BgXIMpaQ6HEpgplNkndYGo7n0Th38m%2BH95kWL2VfvlQCakr%2BPgPFD6wZU7diSJROhEK1C3psHPizaQ8tR0lkLeNhU1pyd%2BUrqstixlNB3WWGTmUprrb8KQIL9mtovIICqeS7C9OcJYfuexWCzLwa%2FGYEMJ%2BWNfCp2AbMx3TZwuXFAMkrkVKFqMnb9mGaa6LC%2F21PlzM1cL1puFcGsArbGLBnd1Lz2YpjLwg7Y1lSQeY7pj34TTYjN%2Fvh71103ZoMKmWoPIFOusB7TGUzgW1dcd6uCiJ3j%2BJsft2LJkf%2FHwkBIPuHdQtpLYNR8ctSUtaJqcc0j72VmH6hqXVxRYotCk2QYzNzMMzWRzFAYywUBO7Io83fkLbEKVJYRf9kuvs%2B8BIxr07C594SolVhAF3T21M1%2BESXxTuOto2Cr7iwoH4WP52Y2twaZXvuJTQJtAHaV0vd0FFkjFSvS5%2Fh6yM9Uu%2Btn6P%2BeAyyPhSTB4N3%2BxmaGnUTC4mtKBqVTsW5zSNdVGB2guRKV2myuUShd8Vdngr3vQZLFOeDzuS50ouzqPQyuoyFC%2FmrdF%2BT5SeM9d3n7iRWw%3D%3D&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20200215T160816Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAQ3PHCVTYSJOKOREH%2F20200215%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=d9fae011bd52f2c6bcacf9c5580b4d25c2c2351baf7e509ea9b96a3a67ad219b&hash=40616796c08538dd9f9b76fd551d7a9a5c7873aa9e0a0df9613a69f718c1e0cc&host=68042c943591013ac2b2430a89b270f6af2c76d8dfd086a07176afe7c76c2c61&pii=0097316580900126&tid=spdf-c181ea23-6ad3-41ca-9c71-1bda7c2cc8b8&sid=d812e6f774c8b94abd8a9a81fce278f35d5agxrqa&type=client).

> It is well known that any permutation of A can be written as a product
> of disjoint cycles. This representation is not strictly unique because
> of ambiguities of order (e.g., (ab)(cd) and (dc)(ab) represent the
> same permutation). However, if a linear order relation is imposed on
> A, then we can pick out a canonical way to write a permutation of A as
> a product of cycles by observing the following rules :
>
> (a) Even trivial cycles of length one are written.
>
> (b) Each cycle is written so that its least member occurs at the end.
>
> (c) The cycles are written so that their least members increase.
>
> Hence, if A = {a, b, c, d, e, f g} with alphabetical order, the
> permutation (a c e) (g d f) has the canonical form (c e a) (b) (f g
> d). Now  in this canonical form the parentheses marking the cycle
> boundaries can be dispensed with; there is no loss of information if
> we write the above permutation simply as the arrangement c e a b f g
> d, because a cycle closes whenever we come to an element which
> precedes in the ordering of A all the elements that follow  it in the
> arrangement. We obtain in this way a one-to-one correspondence between
> the arrangements of A and the permutations of A.

Answer (score 0):

Think about it like this: If I knew the digits in your 5-digit laptop password but did not know the exact order they came in, how many guesses can I attempt to make, assuming I'm lazy and that first step itself took a lot of effort?

So I must type in a first digit. I have five options for this. Consider one of the options, like $4$ maybe. I have four more options left for the second digit. Let's say $3$. I'll then have 3 choices for the third digit and so on. Obviously, after four digits I only have one choice for the fifth digit.

Thus consider this: I have $5$ options for digit $1$, each of which branch out into $4$ possibilities for the second digit, $3$ for the third and so on.

By the way these are permutations because order matters. I won't gain access if I write the digits in the wrong way, otherwise I would have never bothered with this story in the first place.

Consider the branching then. $5$ into $4$ on and on it $1$. This maps our possibility space which becomes: $5 \cdot 4 \cdot 3 \cdot 2 \cdot 1$

Look familiar?