# Counting of permutations (possibly) related to Euler number

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, permutations, generating-functions

I got a question which is somehow related to Euler's number in combinatorics, but I do not know how to make a formal connection.

**Definition**: Given numbers from 1 to $n$, let $G(n,k)$ denote the number of permutations such that the permutation can be decomposed into $k$ groups, $G_1, \cdots, G_k$, where in each $G_i$, $min(G_i)$ is the rightmost one, and $min(G_1)<min(G_2)< \cdots < min(G_k)$.

For instance,

1. for $n=3$ and $k=1$, it could be $(3, 2,1)$ or $(2,3,1)$
2. for $n=3$ and $k=2$, it could be $(3, 1,2)$ or $(2, 1, 3)$ or $(1, 3, 2)$
3. for $n=3$ and $k=3$, it could be $(1, 2,3)$

As a result, $G(3,1)=2, G(3,2)=3$ and $G(3,3)=1$

I want to compute $\sum_{k=1}^n k\cdot G(n,k)$ for a given $n$.

**My attempt**: Interestingly enough, some small example suggests that this is actually $(\sum_{k=1}^n 1/k)\cdot n!$.

My question is whether there is an expression for $G(n,k)$ or $\sum_{k=1}^n k\cdot G(n,k)$?

Answer (score 3):

There is a linear recurrence that can be derived for $G(n,k)$.

Let us see how to insert the element $'n+1'$ into such a permutation. If $'n+1'$ is part of a seperate block, it is forced to be the rightmost element of the permutation and the rest of the $n$ elements have to form a permutation that is counted in $G(n,k-1)$.

Otherwise, $'n+1'$ can be inserted in any of the blocks $G_i$ where it can be any element but the rightmost one in the block. Say, $312$ is our permutation, then $4$ can be inserted either in one of the following spaces:
$$\large{\_312,3\_12,31\_2}$$
Therefore, we would get
$$G(n+1,k)=G(n,k-1)+nG(n,k).$$

Of course, for any recurrence, we need to specify the initial values which you have provided.
$$G(3,0)=0,G(3,1)=2, G(3,2)=3 \text{ and }G(3,3)=1.$$

This should allow us to calculate the values of $G(n,k)$ for $n\geqslant 4,k \geqslant 0$.

Therefore, $G(n,k)$ turns out to be the unsigned Stirling numbers of the first kind.

We can calculate the generating function using this recurrence and that turns out to be $$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}G(n,k)x^k=x(x+1)\cdots(x+n-1).$$

From this, $$\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}kG(n,k)=\dfrac{d\big(\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}G(n,k)x^k \big)}{dx} \Bigg\vert_{x=1}=n!(1+\frac{1}{2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n})$$

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, $G(n,k)$ is equal to the Stirling number of the first kind $n \brack k$, or $S_1(n,k)$. An equivalent definition for $G(n,k)$ is "the number of permutations of $\{1,\dots,n\}$ which have $k$ running minima", where a *running minimum* of a permutation is defined to be an entry which is smaller than all of the numbers which come **after** it. On the other hand, the Stirling numbers of the first kind are the number of permutations of $n$ with $k$ cycles.

To prove $G(n,k)={n\brack k}$, it suffices to find a bijection on permutations which takes a permutation with $k$ cycles to one with $k$ running minima. For this purposes, the [canonical cycle representation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3547657/number-of-all-cycles-in-permutations-is-equal-to-n) of a permutation suffices ([brief mention on wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Canonical_cycle_notation)). Given a permutation with $k$ cycles, write all of those cycles with their smallest element last, and then concatenate them together in increasing order of their last elements. For example, the permutation defined by $1\to 5\to7\to 1$, $2\to 3\to 2$, $4\to 4$, $5\to 8\to 5$, would be written
$$
(5,7,1)\,(3,2)\,(4)\,(8,5)
$$
The key step is then to realize the parentheses are unnecessary; if you delete the parentheses, you can still tell where they were, since a break occurs after every running minimum. The result is
$$
5,7,1,3,2,4,8,5
$$
This is a permutation with four running minima, namely $1,2,4,5$. This is the bijection; the initial permutation had four cycles, the final had four running minima.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a complete answer, but suddenly it occurs to me this is essentially Stirling number of the first kind.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_first_kind